# Stopwatch - Event when it reaches determined time

Tags: c#, events, stopwatch

With C#, I figure some way to:

- Instantiate a Stopwatch
- Start the Stopwatch
- When => | TimeEllapsed of Stopwatch | >=  60000 then
- Call my event which |>
- ByRef disables stopwatch and performs an action

This means that it will have an event that when it reaches 1 minute, gonna run.

For this, I have a closure that is being applied to my customized methods:

```
public static TResult CallWebService<TResult>(Func<TResult> closure)
{
  Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
  timer.Start();
  return closure.Invoke();
}
```

But, as we know, `Stopwatch` hasn't a `Tick` event, like `Timer`. But timer wouldn't meet my needs. I know that there are several other ways to do it, but I figure a way to do it with `Stopwatcher`.

My situation is the following:

I call methods from a webservice and sometimes I receive a timeout. I have dozens of methods that do it. I have a static method that filters then and receive then as first-class-objects. I do all that I need inside `CallWebService`. I will have a timer that will count 1 minute. If in 1 minute the server didn't answer my request, then I'll throw an exception. I did this because the antique were taking about 5 minutes to throw an exception with timeout message. I use compact framework and I'm gonna do it asynchronously.

Comment: Ehr, no. I'll do it asynchronously.

Comment: `Stopwatch` isn't for this. It's for measuring time, and that's about it.

Comment: Ah, Ok. Then I'm gonna use `Timer` instead.

Comment: Why not set the service call timeout for 1 minute? It will throw exception automatically after 1 minute, which you can catch and do whatever you need to do.

Comment: Please, consider adding some comment about votedown. I didn't understand why and I want a reason to I don't repeat the error.

Comment: @TonyCamargo I have put that down as answer. Please accept it as answer if it works for you.

Comment: Yeap. It was exactly what I was wanting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using your own custom timer, just use service call timeout settings. Set it through configuration or set directly in code for 1 minute. It will throw exception after the timeout expires, which you can catch and take any necessary action.

[See this example in msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh924831(v=vs.110).aspx).